# USB ports don't work in Gentoo Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, gentoo, hid

I have a motherboard, **Gigabyte Z170-D3H**, with a fresh **Gentoo** Linux installed (self-compiled kernel **4.9.6-gentoo-r1**) and two USB devices connected (Flashdrive and Mouse). But USB ports **don't work**.

When I type `lsblk`, there is only my system disk `sda`.

`lspci | grep USB` returns:

```
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
```

`lsusb` returns:

```
libusb: debug [libusb_init] created default context
libusb: debug [libusb_init] libusb v1.0.19.10903
libusb: error [op_init] could not find usbfs
unable to initialize libusb: -99
```

`dmesg | grep 'USB\|usb'` returns:

```
[    0.293570] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.293665] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.293756] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.293850] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.987392] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.987449] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.987487] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.987548] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[    0.987592] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.992362] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    0.992376] usbhid: USB HID core driver
```

Here is entire dmesg log: [dmesg_log.txt](https://bison.cf/static/files/dmesg_log.txt)

`usb-devices` returns nothing.

`grep XHCI /usr/src/linux-$(uname -r)/.config` returns:

```
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_PCI=y
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_PLATFORM=y
```

Comment: Can you provide `lsmod` output? Seems you haven't done `modprobe xhci-hcd ` and is compiled as module.

Comment: @sgargel It's very strange, but `lsmod` returns only `Module Size Used by` but nothing more.. What does it mean?

Comment: @BlueManCZ: it's better grep `/proc/config.gz` instead of `/usr/src/linux/.config`. Sometimes they don't match because of a user mistake in either installing the kernel or booting the right one.

Comment: @FrancescoTurco: In my case file /proc/config.gz doesn't exist.

Comment: @BlueManCZ means that no module are loaded at boot. `modprobe -l` usually shows you which modules are available. I don't know if for gentoo is the same but you can specify which module to load in `/etc/modules` or use something like `udev`.

Comment: @BlueManCZ: you need to enable the following kernel options: `CONFIG_IKCONFIG` and especially `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC`

Comment: @sgargel In Gentoo `modprobe -l` doesn't work, but isn't important now. But thank you.

Comment: @FrancescoTurco Yes, these options are both enabled in my .config.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://, chakralinux.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=14008), same error as your, solved with loading module

Answer (score 1):

In the dmesg output, one should see messages like

```
[    1.768941] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.769021] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
...
[    1.787161] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.787880] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
```

(these are from my system) if the kernel detects the USB hardware and assigns drivers, but they are not there.

As modules, you need `xhci_pci` and `ehci_pci` as drivers for the PCI USB controllers (doesn't hurt to have both, and I'm not sure how USB 2.0 on the USB 3.0 hardware is handled, so better include both, at least until the problem is fixed), and `xhci_hcd` and `ehci_hcd` for general support.

Your config screenshot doesn't match your `.config` output, so I'm not sure what your current configuration is. The screenshot says XHCI is a module, your `.config` says it's built-in.

Setting all of them to modules will make debugging easier. So change all 4 to `M`, recompile the kernel, reboot, verify with `lsmod` which are loaded. If none are loaded and in use, `modprobe` the pci variants and see if there are any error messages or any other messages in dmesg/syslog.

If both modules won't load, have a look at the numeric vendor and device id of your controller (`lspci -n`), and verify with `modinfo` or by inspecting the source that the modules should recognize your hardware.

Comment: Thank you for long answer. Yes, you are right, this screenshot is bad. Ok, I will try compile it like modules and put here some results.

Comment: I'm confused. When I use command `modprobe usbcore`, it not return any bad message, so it looks that modul was loaded. But when i type `lsmod`, this returns `Module Size Used by`, but not any modules. Where is the problem? In kernel .config I have more components set to modules, but why this components aren't loaded? When I type `modprobe pcspkr` it returns `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'pcspkr': Exec format error`

Comment: I'm not sure, but very likely because `usbcore` is not used by any other module, so it sees no reason to stay loaded. As I said, use `modprobe xhci_pci` etc., this should automatically load all other required modules. However, `Exec format error` sounds like a serious problem with how you compile modules somewhere. Are modules working at all? Is this your first self-compiled kernel? If yes, try copying the `.config` from a kernel that's known to work, and see if it fixes the problem. Then you've narrowed down the reason.

Comment: Yes, this is my first self-compiled kernel and first gentoo kernel, so I don't have any work kernel config.

Comment: I compiled `xhci_hcd` like module, but when I want to load it, it returns `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'xhci_pci': Exec format error`.

Comment: So either you forgot to enable stuff that's important to load modules, or the way you built your kernel is faulty. I don't know how it works in Gentoo, but in Debian you can access the config of installed stock kernels (i.e., a working config) under `/boot`.

Comment: `to enable stuff that's important to load modules` can you be specific? I don't think that the way of kernel build is faulty. I used this [manual](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Kernel). Yes, maybe I made somewhere mistake, but I don't know where. Gentoo is specific system, you must build and self-kompile kernel before you start using it (live Gentoo's kernel works fine - USB without problem). All my Debian kernels works fine too. But this Gentoo kernel not. Can I look to Debian kernel config and compare it with this Gentoo kernel?

Comment: @BlueManCZ: searching for `modprobe` + `Exec format error` in Gentoo forums I found people saying there's probably a mismatch of some kind between the kernel image and the kernel modules. They suggest to start from scratch (`make clean`). I also suggest to boot a live system such as System Rescue CD, chroot into the system, move kernels from `/boot` to some other location, move modules in `/lib/modules` to some other location too and rebuild the kernel.

Comment: @BlueManCZ: If you have a separate `/boot` partition please make sure it is mounted before installing kernel images.

Comment: I installed new Gentoo system to another disk with kernel configured by `make localyesconfig` on live Gentoo and it works good. USBs are initialized and with `lsusb` I can see them. `/boot` partition was mounted successfully according to `/etc/fstab` conf.